# Google scripts - Array.sort - Operands of compareFunction Reversed?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on understanding how to use array.prototype.sort() in Google Scripts.  My understanding of the compareFunction was that for some array `A = [5,17,10,3]`, when running:

`A.sort(function(a,b){\\some function})`, on the operation of the compareFunction `a == A[0]` and `b==A[1]`. is this not true?  Considering the code below

```js
  var test = [5,17,10,3]

  test.sort(function(a,b){
    Logger.log("a,b")
    Logger.log(a,b)
    Logger.log("a>b")
    Logger.log(a>b)
    return (a-b)

  })
```

When I debug the code with a breakpoint at `Logger.log("a,b")`, on the first pass through, my local variables window states that `a = 17` and `b = 5`.

Am I fully misinterpreting the [two](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) [sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) of documentation I looked at?

Thank you!

Comment: It's implementation-dependent, isn't it? Doesn't matter (and if your code *does* depend on it, the code should be fixed)

Answer (score 2):

The ECMAScript standard does not state which particular `sort` algorithm is used.  (One of the newer standards at least declares it should be a stable-sort.  ES5 does not require this.)

This means that, literally, anything could be under the hood and that the `compare` function can be called in any order.

When I've needed knowledge about the original order of items in an array (forcing a stable-sort), I can through the array and added a new `originalIndex` key for my `compare` function to use.

because your example is using primitives, that's not an easy option.

Answer (score 1):

You might enjoy playing around with something like this:

It's a simple example that shows the power of being able to control the sort function.

```
function getObjectArray() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('source');//sheet name
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,3);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var oA=[];
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    oA.push({name:r[0],haircolor:r[1],worth:r[2]});
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
  return oA;
}

function objectSort(a,b) {
  var hcA=['black','blonde','red','green','blue'];
  var sumA=hcA.indexOf(a.haircolor) + a.worth - parseInt(a.name.slice(4));
  var sumB=hcA.indexOf(b.haircolor) + b.worth - parseInt(b.name.slice(4));
  return sumB-sumA;
}

//Run this function the others are called by it
function ObjectArraySort() {
  var oA=getObjectArray();
  var vA=[];
  oA.sort(objectSort); 
  oA.forEach(function(r,i){
    vA.push([r.name,r.haircolor,r.worth]);
  });
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('source');
  vA.unshift(['Name','HairColor','Worth'])
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,5,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

My source sheet looks like this:

[image]